# Cloudfront, ELB and SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

If i use Cloudfront to sit in front of a webserver, which itself is behind an ELB, would the following apply?

- I use Route53 to create a domain name record for the CF domain and apply an SSL certificate to that domain to secure the distribution
- If CF can not serve the content from the cache then the SSL connection is forward to the the ELB (which fronts the webserver as an origin server)
- Therefore i also need to use the same domain name (FQDN) on the ELB (via Route53 CNAME) and apply the same cert there too?
- When CF forwards the request through the ELB the SSL is terminated
  Is that right ? Will one FQDN cert suffice or better to use a wildcard? Is it better to use the origin server domain name instead?

As i can now use the new AWS certificate manager tool (ACM) to add these certs, does anyone know if CF still require the cost for use of custom SSL cert if using ACM (which makes CF an expensive AWS service)?

Answer (score 17):

> If CF can not serve the content from the cache then the SSL connection is forward to the the ELB (which fronts the webserver as an origin server)

The SSL connection is not "forwarded". A new SSL connection is established between CloudFront and the ELB.

The SSL connection between the user and CloudFront is a completely different connection than the one between CloudFront and the ELB. Therefore, there is not requirements on matching the domain names used on the ELB and CloudFront.

> Therefore i also need to use the same domain name (FQDN) on the ELB (via Route53 CNAME) and apply the same cert there too?

The only restriction is that the SSL certificate on the ELB must match the domain name used on the ELB. It can be a different SSL cert and domain name than those used on CloudFront.

If you want to use the "Custom SSL" feature and support "All Clients", not just those that support SNI, then yes, you must still pay the extra charges, even is you are using ACM.

**Example 1**

You can create Route 53 records for www.domain.com and origin.domain.com and an SSL cert for *.domain.com. From these, you would assign www.domain.com to the CloudFront distribution, origin.domain.com to your ELB, and use the wildcard cert on both.

**Example 2**

You can create Route 53 records for www.domain.com and origin.domain.com and separate SSL certs for www.domain.com and origin.domain.com. From these, you would assign www.domain.com to the CloudFront distribution using the www.domain.com cert, and origin.domain.com to your ELB using the origin.domain.com cert.

**Example 3**

You can create Route 53 records for www.domain1.com and origin.domain2.com and separate SSL certs for www.domain2.com and origin.domain2.com. From these, you would assign www.domain2.com to the CloudFront distribution using the www.domain2.com cert, and origin.domain2.com to your ELB using the origin.domain2.com cert.

Comment: great tks, So just so im 100% clear i could create a suitable domain name for the site, create an AWS cert via ACM and use the same cert for both CF and the ELB? Provided i had created the right DNS records in Route53 (CName and A record). When you say about restriction on the ELB domain name im assuming that isnt the domain name AWS give you for the ELB but a suitable alias ?

Comment: I have added examples.

Comment: For each of these examples that you specified here, what should be the origin name that one should configure in the CF distribution? Can we use the origin name as ELB default DNS name or should i be using the custom domain name that i assigned to ELB.

Comment: I have used the example 2 configuration and i am able to get the CF URL and ALB working , but whenever i click more links on my wordpress website ( for which i am using CF and ALB), i am always getting redirected from my CF URL to ALB URL. I have raised detailed question here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69937819/wordpress-on-aws-why-is-my-cloudfront-url-getting-redirected-to-elb-url]