# How does Cloudfront communicate with ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

INTERNET -> Cloudfront -> ELB -> Instance

Does traffic from Cloudfront to ELB need to be encrypted? Does AWS forward traffic internally or is it a normal public request which would be vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks if not served via https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q) Does traffic from CloudFront to ELB need to be encrypted?

A) No, it does not need to be encrypted, but should be. The trend today is rapidly moving to HTTPS traffic as the preferred protocol. When I configure CloudFront <-> ELB <-> EC2, I setup CloudFront to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, SSL offload at the ELB with traffic between the ELB and EC2 being regular HTTP. The EC2 instances are located in a private subnet without public IP addresses.

Q) Does AWS forward traffic internally or is it a normal public request which would be vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks if not served via https?

A) CloudFront origins are configurable only with AWS credentials. In this case the origin will be the load balancer. To intercept traffic going between CloudFront and an Amazon Load Balancer that is managed by Route 53 DNS servers would be difficult outside of Amazon's network. However, I could not find any reference material on how network traffic is routed between CloudFront and Amazon Load Balancers.

Comment: That's what I did now. Thanks for confirming. Also found these two sources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35157859/1252307 and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-custom-origin.html

Comment: *"CloudFront origins are configurable only with AWS credentials."*  I'm not sure precisely what this means, but depending on your intention, it isn't necessarily accurate.  I have a web server in my bedroom that is configured as a CloudFront origin server. Anything can be a CloudFront Origin... but CloudFront-to-ELB traffic *normally* traverses a global IP network owned and controlled by AWS; however, I believe in a link outage condition there could be exceptions.

Comment: I mentioned that the origin is the load balancer, meaning that it would be very hard if not impossible to intercept communications between them with the added point that the DNS server is also Route 53 so that the DNS names could not be modified. Without Amazon Credentials, you could not modify CloudFront (or Route 53) in order to insert a man in the middle. I also wanted to say that all traffic between CloudFront and Amazon Load Balancers is within Amazon's private network, but I could not find a reference to back that up (although I believe this to be the case).

Comment: ELB => EC2 traffic should still be encrypted with HTTPS as a best practice.

Comment: @WalkingWiki - Do you have an AWS reference for your comment? In my answer I said that in the first line. However, in AWS, SSL offload at the ELB is considered a strong feature. SSL encryption is CPU intensive and offloading this to the ELB reduces CPU load at the instance. Best practices recommend designing systems correctly in a balanced manner taking into consideration security, performance, fault tolerance and scalability.

Answer (score 0):

I used CloudFront --> API Gateway --> Authorizer Lambda --> Route 53 -->  --> HA Proxy --> Trust Verification of API Gateway --> Internal ELB --> EC2

here are more details  http://knowmg.blogspot.com/2017/11/why-do-i-need-haproxy-in-aws-stack.html